# Regular Expression for adding meta tag, if it does not exist (notepad++)

Tags: html, regex, notepad++, meta-tags

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that will be applied for potentially hundreds of files, as a find..replace in notepad++. It's going to be like an if..else.

Here's what I want to do but as a regex:

if title tag exists and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` does not exist on the page, AND an iframe tag exists, then insert `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` right after the title tag.

Sample text:

```
<title>Some Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="Mydescription." />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

 ...

<iframe src="iframeresource"></iframe>
```

Regex I have thus far:

```
(<title>.*<\s*\/title>).*?(?!<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"\s*\/>.*?<iframe)
```

It uses a negative lookahead. I need something like a conditional negative lookahead but the ability to perform substitution, if and only if `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge />` does not exist already. I'm not quite sure how to do this with straight regex.

Any ideas would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use notepad++ to do that, use the language you want with a DOM parser. I will be more simple than a text approach.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the suggestion. A DOM parser would be ideal here. However, this is just to fix several hundred files in multiple locations and I need something quick. Unfortunately, using what is the best practice approach will require more time, which I don't have for this particular task. I would think there would be a way with regex. But I knew it wouldn't be a simple regex. Thanks again for your insight.

Comment: Even if you have several hundred files, doing it with notepad++ means you have to add forward and backward test to your pattern, and you will end with something not efficient.

Comment: Something inefficient but hopefully, it will solve your issue: https://regex101.com/r/Rw5w1Y/1

Comment: Wiktor: You are a genius! I think that works. Thank you! How'd you figure that out? I'm not sure I understand how it works. For your regex: `(?si)\A(?!.*?<meta\s+http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"\s+content="IE=edge"\s*/>)(.*?<title>.*?</title>)(.*)`, you have `\A` and then the meta tag. Shouldn't this fail since the title tag comes before the meta tag at the start of the test string? I see that it works, but I don't quite understand why.

Comment: Well, it is easy: `(?si)` enables `.` to match linebreaks and makes the pattern case insensitive. `\A` matches the start of a file. The `(?!.*?<meta\s+http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"\s+content=‌​"IE=edge"\s*/>)` fails the match if the meta tag pattern is matched. `(.*?<‌​title>.*?</title>)` consumes and captures text up to and including the first `title` tag. Then `(.*)` matches the rest of the document. And it can be optimized further for better performance, but if it works as is, great.

Comment: Oh OK, yes. Thank you. That makes sense. It seems to work. If there is an optimized version of it that you aware of, that'd be excellent. If you don't, that's OK, too. Thanks again for your help. Made it simpler than it needed to be. If you like, you can create an answer to the question so I can checkmark it.

Comment: @user3621633: I posted an answer below to finalize this question. As I do not get any points for this community wiki answer, please consider upvoting [any 2 (and only 2) of my other NPP regex related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a3832970%20%5bnotepad%2b%2b%5d).

Answer (score 1):

HTML parsing is best done with a dedicated DOM parser. A regex can only be used to fix a well-structured, consistent HTML code.

If this is the case, use

```
(?si)\A(?!.*?<meta\s+http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"\s+content="IE=edge"\s*/>)(.*?<title>.*?</title>)(.*)
```

and replace with `$1\n<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />$2\n`.

`(?si)` enables `.` to match linebreaks and makes the pattern case insensitive. `\A` matches the start of a file. The `(?!.*?<meta\s+http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"\s+content=‌​"IE=e‌​dge"\s*/>)` fails the match if the meta tag pattern is matched. `(.*?<‌​title>.*?</title>)` consumes and captures text up to and including the first `title` tag. Then `(.*)` matches the rest of the document.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rw5w1Y/1)